# Show data on Chart instead of tooltip

Tags: google-visualization

Using Google pie charts
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24j36joz/2/)

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     20],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2]
        ]);
```

How can I get the 'Hours per Day' to show in the chart itself. Now it is showing in the tooltip mouseover. For example mouseover on Eat will show 2. When I save/print the chart I can't get these items. How to show this on the chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `pieSliceText` [configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options) allows you to change what appears on each slice

to get the value of the row, use...
`pieSliceText: 'value'`

also, if the chart isn't big enough, it will omit the label

there are several ways to size the chart
you can style the `div` container,
or set the height and width in the options

also, google recommends waiting on the chart's `'ready'` event,
before calling any methods, including [`getImageURI`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing)

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     20],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2]
    ]);

    var options = {
      height: 400,
      legend: {
        position: 'labeled',
        textStyle: {
          color: 'blue'
        }
      },
      pieSliceText: 'value',
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      width: 800
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      document.getElementById('image_div').innerHTML = '<img alt="Chart" src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
    });

    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="image_div"></div>
```